# Passing arguments to bash with awk command to filter

Tags: bash, text-processing, awk

I would like to ask some help how can I improve the basic script below.

So, I was able to pass the arguments to bash, but is it possible for my awk command, to make it more flexible?

I encountered an error in `df -h` command where it shows 2 lines for 1 filesystem (supposed to be one line only)

and then, the script does not show correct parameters since argument numbers (the `$6` and `$5`) have changed.

Sample:

```
df -h

Filesystem                   Size            Used  Avail  Use% Mounted on
/dev/test/test2/test3        1.1G            100M  1G     1%   /test
/dev/test/test2/test3/test4
                          1.1G            100M  1G     1%   /tst2


$ cat myscript.sh
#!bin/bash

df -h "$@" | awk '{print $6,"=",$5}' | sed -n '1!p'

$ ./myscript.sh /test /tst2
```

My output will be

```
/test=1%

=/tst2
```

but should be

```
/test=1%

/tst2=1%
```

Comment: `awk '{print $NF,"=",$(NF -1)}'`. You can get rid of the `sed` as well...

Comment: Oh, Thank you, I think its working correctly now. I will retest this. very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use this instead and you won't have to worry about post processing the `df` output.

`df -P`

This will make sure output for 1 filesystem does not span over multiple lines.

So your final script will be

`df -h -P "$@" | awk '{ print $6,"=",$5}' | sed -n '1!p'`

Comment: I'd suggest `LANG=C LC_ALL=C df -h -P "$@" | ...`, just to ensure the output always uses the POSIX/C locale, so that the decimal point is always a `.`. In some locales, like the one I prefer to use (`fi_FI.utf8`), the decimal point is a comma `,`, and that confuses many scripts.